# BSODs after Windows 8.1 Upgrade

Tags: bsod, windows-8.1, minidumps, windows-8.1-upgrade

I just upgraded my system to Windows 8.1, and I have been getting BSODs that I did not get before the 8.1 upgrade. Though I cannot conclude that running the Android Emulator with Intel's HAXM is the cause, both crashes have occurred while the emulator was running.

I get CRITICAL_STRUCTURE_CORRUPTION, the same error as [this guy](https://superuser.com/questions/653421/windows-8-1-rtm-bsod-with-fault-critical-structure-corruption), except I don't have the hardware/software that he has that caused his problem. Minidumps [here](http://sdrv.ms/17YiK3z).

Output of verifier.exe /all and then a reboot and then verifier /query: http://sdrv.ms/17CPVu9

Edit: According to http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/475129 it is being caused by HAXM. Will close question when I find a solution.

Comment: Don't close it if you find a solution, instead post it as an answer (you're allowed to do that). :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A hotfix for this issue is now available. Download here: http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager